# how to flip array of images in viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, core-graphics

i am learning core animation in iOS first thing i have to know how to flip array of images in view

here my sample codes:

```
NSArray *animationArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"homebg.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash.jpg"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"index3.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"image4.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"index6.png"],
                         nil];

imageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor purpleColor];
imageView.animationImages=animationArray;
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
imageView.animationDuration=3.9;
imageView.animationRepeatCount=0;
[imageView startAnimating];
```

it worked but i am not satisfied i want images to be animated and attract the end user

Comment: why dont you save flipped images in another array and do the animation one after another ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// in view Load
_slide = 0
[self changeSlide];

// Loop gallery 
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:5.0f target:self selector:@selector(changeSlide) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];


- (void)changeSlide
{

if(_slide > _galleryImages.count-1) _slide = 0;

UIImage *toImage = [UIImage imageNamed:_galleryImages[_slide]];
[UIView transitionWithView:_yourimageView
                  duration:0.6f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:^{
                    _yourimageView.image = toImage;

                } completion:nil];
_slide++;
//    }
}
```

Create  a Timer and Array Of images .Animate ur images with various `Flip`Animation option,Hope this helps you

[image]

Comment: thanx for ur Answer may i know what is _slide i mean its declaration ?

Comment: its an integer default value is `0`.`_galleryImages[_slide]` helps to access the image with index and incrementing

Comment: use any one of animation `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft|UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight |UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop |UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom`

Comment: i also attched the demo how its working for me.check the edit.